# Unable to log into Facebook page on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, facebook

I have a "community/organisation" page on Facebook as well as my personal account. I can log into my personal page fine but whenever I attempt to log into the community page,I get a "Problem loading page" screen with the message:

**The page isn’t redirecting properly**

**An error occurred during a connection to www.facebook.com.**

**This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.**

**Try again.**

From that point on, I get the same message/screen whenever I try to visit the Facebook website at all. I can only rectify this by clearing cookies under "clear history". After that, I am able to view the Facebook site again and log into my personal account and I can also view the community page but I am still unable to log into the account for that page. Attempting to log into this page results in the error message/screen again. I am effectively locked out of my Facebook community page. Even rebooting doesn't change this.

I'm using Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS (bionic) and Firefox version 77.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an "anonymous" account to maintain the community page? The one that was once possible to create automatically when you did create a page on Facebook? (it's no more possible since several years)

Facebook did not fully support those accounts since some time and recently messed up something with them pretty badly. It's impossible to login from any recent browser, be it Linux or Windows, Firefox or Chrome (technically, you are logged in, but once logged in, no page on Facebook works - that's why it starts to work again when you clear the cookies, because by clearing the cookies you log out). Personal accounts work OK.

It's neither an Ubuntu nor Firefox issue. It's a Facebook issue. Unless you have an additional admin on your community page, you're probably out of luck... :( Or you can try on some computer with older browser, maybe it will work...

Comment: Scumbags. I never knew about that. I wonder what they "messed up" exactly. I'm deleting my personal FB account after this and ditching them forever.